# Looping through a local storage array returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

Context: I have an array created from a collection of string entries pushed to local storage. I then loop through these entries and find a matched value from an array of objects. It should bring back the matched object.

Issue: I can get it to return the matched object only when using mock data in the applications typescript file. However, when I introduce the local storage to replace the mocked up array of pushed values the resulting object returns undefined. What I cant understand is that the console logs before the mapping is executed does shoe that the two querying arrays including that of the local storage are ready and the same as if it was mock data.

I have created an example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-select-dropdown-xqonq9?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) that is also showing the error. I have created two loops in the example. One for the local storage and one for the mock data.

I am using an Angular application so for demo purposes I have pushed to local storage in the constructor and populated the array in `ngOnInit()`. Usually the local storage would be populated on another page but for ease of demoing this represented a similar scenario with the same outcome.

```
 export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    //passing data into local storage
    let data = ["1", "2"];
    const key = "item";
    let id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];
    if (id.indexOf(data) == -1) {
      id.push(data);
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(id));
    }
  }

  array = [];
  arrayTwo = ["1", "2"];
  fieldOptions = [
    {
      id: "1",
      type: "I_am_RED",
      displayKey: "I_am_RED"
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      type: "I_am_RED",
      displayKey: "I_am_RED"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      type: "I_am_BLUE",
      displayKey: "I_am_BLUE"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      type: "I_am_BLUE",
      displayKey: "I_am_BLUE"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      type: "I_am_GREEN",
      displayKey: "I_am_GREEN"
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const key = "item";
    this.array.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)));

    //local storage loop
    for (const item of this.array) {
      let obj = this.fieldOptions.find(o => o.id === item);
      console.log("Array Object result getting local storage", obj);
    }

    //mock loop - mock array to simulate local storage
    for (const item of this.arrayTwo) {
      let obj = this.fieldOptions.find(o => o.id === item);
      console.log("ArrayTwo Object result", obj);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `[ 1, 2 ] != [ 1, 2 ]` - don't forget that _objects_ are always unique and an array is an object. Even if it contains the same elements, it will _never_ be the same _array_. You will have to do a deeper comparison of the object to see if it matches. Also, a JSON parse error for a non existing object might also cause this. Try `JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem || "[]" )` to ensure you _always_ get back at least a valid array.

Comment: You should do this:     `for (const item of this.array) {
      console.log(item)
      console.log(this.fieldOptions)` You re matching wrong things. Use `item[0][0]` or `item[0][1]` And you will match it against  1 or 2 to `ids` or go one level up item[0] and loop and do for each.

Comment: Seems like this is the issue - i cant use [0] as that value will always change e.g. could be [??] amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding array of array in localstorage. Try below code :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { forEach } from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    //passing data into local storage
    let data = ["1", "2"];
    const key = "item";
    let id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) || [];

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (id.indexOf(data[i]) == -1) {
        id.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(id));
  }

  array = [];
  arrayTwo = ["1", "2"];
  fieldOptions = [
    {
      id: "1",
      type: "I_am_RED",
      displayKey: "I_am_RED"
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      type: "I_am_RED",
      displayKey: "I_am_RED"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      type: "I_am_BLUE",
      displayKey: "I_am_BLUE"
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      type: "I_am_BLUE",
      displayKey: "I_am_BLUE"
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      type: "I_am_GREEN",
      displayKey: "I_am_GREEN"
    }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    const key = "item";
    this.array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    console.log("get storage", this.array);

    for (const item of this.array) {
      let obj = this.fieldOptions.find(o => o.id === item);
      console.log("Array Object result getting local storage", obj);
    }

    for (const item of this.arrayTwo) {
      let obj = this.fieldOptions.find(o => o.id === item);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the constructor, "data" is an array of strings. indexOf() will try to compare object identities, not content, so `id.indexOf(data)` will *always* be -1
(because `["1", "2"] == ["1", "2"]` is falsy).

in ngOnInit you are pushing an array to another array, is that actually what you want? my guess would be that you'd probably want to use `this.array = this.array.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)))`

Comment: The above are really good pointers - I don't really need the indexOf, that was previously there to stop the id being pushed to local storage more than once. The issue still remains that the local storage data after being looped is returning undefined

Comment: you are still pusing an array to an array, so you end up having an array of arrays, which means that you are trying to compare an array to a single string.